# HJM framework problem - showing that HJM drift condition implies that $b(z)=b+βz$ and $(ρ)^2=α$

Tags: interest-rates, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, heath-jarrow-morton

Hi I am looking for some general clarification to Heath–Jarrow–Morton framework. I am analyzing a problem where the forward rate is modeled as
$$ f(t,T)=e^{\beta(T-t)} Z_t+h(T-t)  \tag{1}$$
for some constant $\beta$ and some smooth function $h:R \rightarrow \ R \ with \quad h(0)=0$ and some scalar diffusion
$$dZt=b(Z_t)dt+\rho dW_t^* \tag{2}$$
with continuous drift and functions $b(z)$ and $\rho(z)$.

To show that HJM drift condition implies that $\ \mathbf{b(z)=b+\beta z} \ $ and  $\ \mathbf{(\rho)^2=\alpha} \ $ for some constant b and $\alpha$

**Q1** 
**Can anybody explain in simple terms what this above statement mean? what needs to be showed/proved? I am confused here what is the relation between the variables given in the  equations (1) and (2) with those $\alpha$ and b.**

There is the analyzes I have done  on this problem. I understand the most of the transformations, but some points are unclear.

Taking the derivative of $f(t,T)$ in order to get $df(t,T)$ and substituting for $dz_t$ I get
$$df(t,T)=\big{(} -h'(T-t)+e^{\beta(T-t)}(b(z_t)-\beta z) \big{)} \  dt+e^{\beta(T-t)} \rho(z_t) dW_t^* \tag{3} $$
the Q-dynamics of the forward rates in HJM framework are of the form
$$f(t,T)=f(0,T) + \int_0^t \big{(}  \sigma(s,T) \int_s^T \sigma(s,u) \ du \big{)} \ ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s,T) dW_t^* \tag{4}$$ 
or equivalently
$$ df(t,T)= \sigma(t,T) \int_t^T \sigma(t,u) \ du + \sigma(s,T) dW_t^*\tag{5}$$
therefore the HJM drift equals 
$$e^{\beta(T-t)} \rho(z_t) \int_t^T e^{\beta(u-t)} \rho(z_t) \ du =\rho(z_t)^2 e^{\beta(T-t)} \frac{ e^{-\beta t}}{\beta} (e^{\beta T} - e^{\beta t})  \tag{6}$$
equating HJM drift with drift from eq (3) and substituting for $\tau=T-t$ yields the following equity
$$ \frac{\rho(z_t)^2}{\beta}  e^{\beta \tau}  (e^{\beta \tau} - 1) = -h'(\tau)+e^{\beta \tau}(b(z_t)-\beta z)   \tag{7}$$
assuming $\tau=0$ results in
$$ b(z)=h'(0)+\beta z  \tag{8}$$
comparing with the given equation
$$b(z)=b+ \beta z \tag{9}$$
we can infer that $b=h'(0)$
finally plugging $b(z)$ (8) into (7)  gives the $alpha$ value
$$\rho^2= \frac{\beta(e^{\beta \tau} h'(0)- h'(t))}{e^{\beta \tau}(e^{\beta \tau}-1)} \tag{10}$$
$$\alpha=\rho^2$$

**Further questions to this problem 

b and $\alpha$ have been derived from the drift condition. I don't understand in what sense does it prove the initial question? 

Does it implicitly mean that the RHS of (10) is a constant? 

what is the relation between the HJM drift and the coefficient of $dW_t^
*$ in (3)?**

Comment: Should $h(T-1)$ be $h(T-t)$ in (1)?

Comment: @Gordon , you are right, it should be h(T-t) there I corrected the typo, sorry

Comment: I made some further typo corrections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost get there. However, you ca not conclude that $\rho^2$ is a constant based on $(10)$. Note that, from your $(7)$ and $(8)$, 
\begin{align*}
 \frac{\rho(z_t)^2}{\beta}  e^{\beta \tau}  (e^{\beta \tau} - 1) = -h'(\tau)+e^{\beta \tau}h'(0).
\end{align*}
Taking derivative with respect to $\tau$ on both sides, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\rho(z_t)^2}{\beta} \left(2\beta e^{2\beta \tau} -\beta e^{\beta \tau}\right) = -h''(\tau)+\beta e^{\beta \tau}h'(0).
\end{align*}
Then, setting $\tau=0$, 
\begin{align*}
\rho(z_t)^2 = -h''(0)+\beta h'(0).
\end{align*}
That is, $\rho(z_t)^2=\alpha$ is a constant, where $\alpha = -h''(0)+\beta h'(0)$.